# the onchange event of an input is not detected

Tags: html

I have this html code:

```
<input list="selectedStructureId" onchange="getStructure(this.value)">
<datalist style="display:none" id="selectedStructureId">                        
    <option th:each="s : ${structures}" th:value="${s.id}"      
    th:text="${s.libelleStructure}"></option>
</datalist>
```

The onchange event of the input is not detected unless I click out of it!!
I wanna it be fired when I select an item of my datalist!

Answer (score 0):

I have to use the `onselect` event and not the onchange event !